# Where can I get instructions for a daily stretching routine?

Tags: exercise, stretching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Daily stretch routine to increase flexibilty and overall fitness?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/daily-stretch-routine-to-increase-flexibilty-and-overall-fitness)

I run to keep fit, but a combination of poor warm up/down routines and hours at a desk every day have lead to very stiff muscles - I can barely touch my knees let alone my toes. Are there any good resources for a daily stretching routine, ideally no more than 20-30 mins, that can help me regain flexibility?

Answer (score 0):

Check out 
[Daily stretch routine to increase flexibilty and overall fitness?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/daily-stretch-routine-to-increase-flexibilty-and-overall-fitness/2941#2941)

Then since you are a runner, you most likely need stretches for your lower extremities, including:

- heel cords - gastroc and soleus
- hamstrings
- quads
- hip flexors
- hip abductors and lateral thigh
- hip adductors
- hip rotators - internal and external
- glutes

Also, given your prolonged sitting you will want to make sure that you stretch your spine and trunk muscles.  I like Joseph Weisberg’s 3 Minute overall stretch.    Ming Chew also has a nice set of stretches for the spine and fascia.  Then they each also have good stretches for individual muscles where you need emphasis.  For more detail on these two [books](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Stretching.html).  20 - 30 minutes is plenty of time.

The foam roller is a nice method for massaging and releasing tight muscles by yourself.   For example, here is a [video using a foam roller](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9aJtO0VCqw) to release the TFL/ITBand.

A stretching strap helps esp. with hamstring and hip flexor/quad stretches.   This video shows how to combine a [stretch out strap with a PNF contract - relax](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jxu5lzpxX0Y) method.