# Why I can't touch my toes and how to fix it?

Tags: flexibility, gymnastics, mobility

I cannot bend down and touch my toes,I could reach only till my shins...I am 21,5'6 and play sports regularly.I cannot even reach my toes when sitting. It's not a new problem, I've always not able to reach toes.I feel tightness in my hamstrings when I try nevertheless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stretch hamstrings in isolation?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-can-i-stretch-hamstrings-in-isolation)

Comment: Hamstrings are not always the culprit of toe-touching inflexibility. https://breakingmuscle.com/fitness/cant-touch-your-toes-find-and-fix-the-root-of-the-problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you a hot bath kind of person? Sit in a hot bath for 3 minutes and try to touch your toes while sitting. Or if your gym has a sauna, sweat it out for 5 minutes, then try to touch your toes. Like anything, practice makes perfect, i.e., consistency.

---

Another good way is to get into a "sumo pose," touch the floor, then lock out your knees so your legs are in an "A" shape with your hands touching the floor still. Keep doing that gradually bringing your feet closer together as you do it.

Answer (score 1):

> **[If you have 5 minutes here you go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJMRdusSY4Y).**

**Magic**

*Note: This works - but this may not be addressing the actual issue as Eric said above.*

Answer (score -1):

Hi i will try to answer not because i know the science behind it but from experience. So i was taking my boyfriend to yoga with me and he had the same problem. couldn't touch his toes. The yoga instructor advised him to bend his knees a little when we folded over. for like a month, he will bend his knees and touch his toes but hold the pose for about a minute. it helps stretch those lower back muscles initially which are really tight. he will will do that repeatedly about 3 times a day, holding the pose for a minute or longer if he chose to. Then he started to bend his knees less and less and now he can touch his toes. it took him about 6 months to get there. I will suggest doing the same thing with daily consistency. you've never used those lower back muscles befor that's why they are stiff. so you have to train them to loosen up little by little. hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice,from all the resources I come to know that there might be two causes,one as you said tightness in lower back and tight hamstrings.Will try the fixes.

Comment: Actually you use those lower back muscles every day to sit, stand, walk, balance, etc. One of the reasons for low back pain is that for many, the lower back muscles are much more developed than the abdominals. Also, we encourage answers to be backed with actual science, rather than anecdotes.